# Year slug for pages not allowed

Tags: permalinks, pages

I want create http://siteurl/2022 or http://siteurl/2023 page. but when i create page, page slug automatically change to 2022-2 and 2023-2

- wordpress is fresh install and no post, page or attachment exist in database, and when i call http://siteurl/2022 get 404 error page
- I cant find any document about reserved slug for pages related year name
- I tried this on 4 other sites and the result was the same

Why does this happen?

Comment: WordPress disallows numbers as the post slug because it can conflict with yearly or date-based archives, e.g. the 2023 archive at `example.com/2023`.